# perl: make script fast to use big file

Tags: perl

My problem is how to make my script fast (I use big files)

I have the script above it add "bbb" between words if the words exist in an other file that contain sequences of words 
for exemple file2.txt : `i eat big pizza .my big pizza ...`
file1.txt (sequences):

```
                          eat big pizza
                          big pizza
```

the result Newfile

```
i eatbbbbigbbbpizza.my bigbbbpizza ...
```

my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open Newfile ,">./newfile.txt" or die "Cannot create Newfile.txt";
 my %replacement;
my ($f1, $f2) = ('file1.txt', 'file2.txt');

open(my $fh, $f1);
my @seq;
foreach (<$fh> )
{
  chomp;
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
  push @seq, $_;
}
close $fh;

@seq = sort bylen @seq;

open($fh, $f2);
foreach (<$fh> ) {
  foreach my $r (@seq) {

    my $t = $r;
    $t =~ s/\h+/bbb/g;

    s/$r/$t/g;
  }
  print Newfile ;
}
close $fh;
close Newfile ;
exit 0;

sub bylen {
   length($b) <=> length($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array

```
my @seq;
```

define your words as a hash.

```
my %seq;
```

Instead of pushing the words

```
push @seq, $_;
```

store the words in the hash. Precalculate the replacement and move it out of the loop.

```
my $t = $_;
$t =~ s/\h+/bbb/g;
$seq{$_} = $t;
```

Precalculate the words in front of the outer loop:

```
my @seq = keys %seq;
```

And use hash look-ups to find the replacement in the inner loop:

```
my $t = $seq{$r};
```

This might be a bit faster, but do not expect too much.

In most cases it is better to reduce the problem by preparing the input in a way, which makes the solution easier. For example `grep -f` is much faster than your Perl loops. Use grep to find the lines, which need a replacement, and do the replacement with Perl or Sed.

Another way is to parallel the job. You can divide your input in n parts and run n processes on n CPUs in parallel. See the [GNU parallel tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

What about a regexp like this (beware that this approach can cause security concerns) ?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $Newfile, '>', 'newfile.txt') or die "Cannot create Newfile.txt: $!";
my ($f1, $f2) = qw(file1.txt file2.txt);

open (my $fh, $f1) or die "Can't open $f1 for reading: $!";
my @seq = map {split ' ', $_ } <$fh>;
close $fh;
# an improvement would be to use an hash to avoid dupplicates

my $regexp = '(' . join('|', @seq) . ')';

open($fh, $f2) or die "Can't open $f2 for reading: $!";
foreach my $line (<$fh> ) {
    $line =~ s/$regexp/$1bbb/g;
    print $Newfile $line;
}
close $fh;
close $Newfile ;
exit 0;
```